# SISS - Automatically Create Column ( Derived Colomn)

Tags: visual-studio, ssis, integration

I would like to now, if has a way to create automatically columns on Data Conversion (SISS) .

I have an Excel Source with a `med19g` (which represents 2019 year).

[image]

Next step, I have my Data Conversion:

[image]

As you see, `med19g` columns is on it.

So, next year will be added a `med20g` (represents 2020 year) column in Excel, and I'd like to find a way to add this column automatically or way to prevent that column on my solution (Data Conversion).

Does someone have any idea how I can I get it?

I'm using Visual Studio 2015

Thanks in advance

Comment: You will need to use "Derived Column" under Data Flow Transformation category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use "Flat file source" in the data flow to get the source file. After that, Use "Derived Column" under Data Flow Transformations category and add the desired field like below:

[image]

You can edit your output column name later by using Advanced Editor (Right click on Derived column)

[image]

If you need to check whether your source file has the same column or not already, you can add a "Script Component" (Source) between the "Get Flat File" and "Derived Column" components. In the script, check your column names and use a boolean value to decide if a column name is existing already or not. How you can do is explained clearly in this link:
https://dichotic.wordpress.com/2006/11/01/ssis-test-for-data-files-existence/

Comment: I think so, yes. Not hard to change an excel sheet to csv but.

Comment: I picked up your solution , but im still facing that problem . 

Id like to  create all the years without develop in the future my solution .

Its something like , IF that column has in excel  PUT IT , if not pass !